# media discoverers in libvlcsharp doesn't display webcams

Tags: webcam, libvlcsharp

Media discoverer doesn't find video capture devices in this code :

```cs
            Core.Initialize();

            using var libvlc = new LibVLC();

            foreach (MediaDiscovererCategory val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MediaDiscovererCategory)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"===== {val}  ======");
                var mds = libvlc.MediaDiscoverers(val);

                Console.WriteLine($" number of mds: {mds.Count()}");
                foreach (var dm in mds)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{dm.Category} {dm.Name} {dm.LongName}");
                    //display only disc
                }

                if (mds.Any(x => x.LongName == "Video capture"))
                {
                    var devices = mds.First(x => x.LongName == "Video capture");
                    var md = new MediaDiscoverer(libvlc, devices.Name);
                    md.Start();
                    foreach (var media in md.MediaList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($" _ {media.Mrl}");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

in response i should get 3 webcams or video grabbers connected to my machine, but there i get only this:

result:

===== Devices  ======
number of mds: 1

Devices disc Discs

===== Lan  ======
number of mds: 3
Lan microdns mDNS Network Discovery
Lan sap Network streams (SAP)
Lan upnp Universal Plug'n'Play

===== Podcasts  ======
number of mds: 3

Podcasts podcast Podcasts

Podcasts lua{sd='jamendo'} Jamendo Selections

Podcasts lua{sd='icecast'} Icecast Radio Directory

===== Localdirs  ======
number of mds: 3

Localdirs video_dir My Videos

Localdirs audio_dir My Music

Localdirs picture_dir My Pictures

Comment: I don't think webcam discovery is part of the libvlc features